# ¿Es posible crear una regla htaccess donde un archivo APK se abra al redireccionar una ruta declarada?

Tags: .htaccess

Archivo .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule confirm         confirm.apk
```

Archivo index.php

```
<?php
header('Location: confirm');
?>
```

Archivo apk :vacio

Lo que intento replicar es el comportamiento que tienen los archivos php llamados y reconocidos por el navegador sin extension al tener la regla declarada
,es decir,
lo mismo que obtengo al llamar el archivo confirm cuando en el htacess tiene extension .php,.js, etc...

El navegador no me abre ese archivo, ni lo descarga al no ser web.

Comment: ¿Un archivo APK o una aplicación de Android? Si se trata de lo segundo, una aplicación solo abre URLs compatibles. https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0):

Partimos de esto

No puedes abrir un apk directamente desde un navegador dado que este es un formato propio de android.

Ahora, en cuanto al htaccess no sé si sea la mejor opción para abrir (más bien descargar) ese archivo apk

Hay ciertas cosas que influyen en la lógica de abrir ese enlace.

Te recomiendo hacer un archivo .php (O del lenguaje que uses) para establecer la cabecera de descarga del archivo.